# React-native: call a function on go back from a scene

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working in an app that it have to pass data between scenes or views. My escenario is simple, I have a Navigator component as a father of two scenes:

1. Dashboard: Contains a listview with some data.
2. Details: Shows the data of the element selected in the previous listview.

The next lines explains the behaviour I want to get:

1. Enter to Dashboard: request the data from rest server and draw it in the listview.
2. Go to Details: select an item from the dashboard.
3. Modify an item: Modify a property of the item that I selected, then go back.
4. Return to Dashboard: request the data from rest server and draw it in the listview (like the first point, I want to get new data if it was generated from point one to third.

**My question is about how can I refresh my scene or call a function of the scene when it takes the focus(the fourth point explained above). This is so because it wasn't unmounted.**

I've also checked the react-native docs an I tried with the next methods componentWillReceiveProps(), shouldComponentUpdate(), componentWillUpdate(),etc. but none worked.

Thanks you.

Comment: What you are using for navigation is very relevant

Comment: How you do this depends on which navigation library you are using.

Comment: I'm using the default Navigator library of React-native-> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out react-redux . Setting state/properties at global level will pass properties across screens. The components are also re-rendered based on the properties used.

Another option would be to pass props to the dashboard component if there are any changed made in the detail.Based on the properties passed you can trigger the RefreshControl for Dashboard(ListView)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to check redux library.

Comment: Finally I solved my issue using react-redux. Thank you all for your help.